# Wordpress! 403 Error message and redirect to wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress

I got 403 Error message on wp-login page, Also its redirects to `"/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Ffutureeducation.info%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"` URL.

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong site url, in https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress try to follow "Changing Your Domain Name and URLs" with a correct url

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but I have both "site url" and "home" url are same and correct on wp_options table as given below
"http://futureeducation.info/"

Comment: ah, ok, try to disable permalinks, if helps it's something in there, have you got some security plugin?

Comment: try to rename your plugin folder as plugin_old and check after that. It seems there is a conflict ion due to plugin or theme

Comment: also add this to your .htaccess file 
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @Pardeep Pathania I tried your solution but it's doesn't work for me

Comment: now change code of your .htaccess with mine code

Comment: @fiorebat No, i don't have any security plugin

Comment: try rename .htaccess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it fixed by emailing to my hosting provide services, that was due to some update on server side